# Could not locate bookmark due to data movement

Tags: sql-server, vmware

We got this Error in one of our SQL-Jobs tonight:

> *Error: Executing the query "exec P_ALL" failed with the following error: "Could not locate bookmark due to data movement.". Possible
>   failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set
>   correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established
>   correctly.*

I can't find any explanation on the web. The MS SQL Server 11.0.7462.6 is running on VMware. It is noticeable that the error came exactly at 03:00:13 am.

I know it is not easy to say, but do you think it is possible, that the VM moved the data and because of that, the Job failed? Do you know other reasons for this error?

The event error log has no further Information.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: I don't think this error is related to virtualization. Are you using the `READ UNCOMMITTED` isolation level or `NOLOCK` hint?

Comment: No, we don't use one of these hints.